# Discord.js | why doesnt my index.html dashboard button send to the correct URL

Tags: javascript, discord.js, uri

> I tried running a discord music bot from this repository: https://github.com/SudhanPlayz/Discord-MusicBot

I have an other issue, when i try to access the dashboard on the website of the music bot, it get **invalid OAuth2 redirect_uri**. I even made sure i gave all the necessary permissions. In the developper portal i entered my redirect url: *https://discord-musicbot.skoobary.repl.co/api/callback*

With all this it still didnt work so i went into the index.html and server.html and replaced the url with a url that i generated from the url generator in the developper portal.

For the scopes i gave it **bot, aplication.commands, identify, guilds** and for the permissions **administrator**. And even with this it doesnt work.

When I try to access the dashboard with the modified url in the html i noticed that it doesnt send me to my url but to an other one.

> my url : https://discord.com/api/oauth2/authorize?client_id=834790647889657926&permissions=8&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fdiscord-musicbot.skoobary.repl.co%2Fapi%2Fcallback&response_type=code&scope=guilds%20identify%20bot%20applications.commands

> The url that the site sends me to : https://discord.com/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2FDiscord-MusicBot.skoobary.repl.co%2Fapi%2Fcallback&scope=identify%20guilds%20applications.commands&client_id=834790647889657926

Here is a link for an image of my URI in the discord developer portal

> https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7BO1.png

i already did everything from this and it still doesnt work
The thing is that the url does work, but the when i try to get to the url from the website it doesnt work because instead of sending me to my url, it sends me to another one
i have been working on this issue for over 2days now, and i still can find the solution

Answer (score 0):

i think you have too much authorisation on the oauth2, like bot, application.commands, administrator and guilds, you just need to have identify activated.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).